OR statement in conditional probability: P(A|B or C)
I was reading about the Fine-Gray model for competing risks, and the definition[1,2] given for the subdistribution hazard function is:
$$\lambda(t) := \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{P \left( T \leq t + \Delta t, \epsilon = 1|T \geq t \bigcup [T \leq t \cap \epsilon \neq 1] \right)}{\Delta t}$$
where $T$ is the failure time, and $\epsilon$ is the cause of failure. I am interpreting the $\cup$ symbol as "OR" and $\cap$ as "AND" - but maybe this is incorrect?
I've never seen a probability statement of the form $P(A|B \cup C)$, a simple contrived example would be the probability of heads for a Bernoulli($p$) given that $p=0.25$ or $p=0.8$: $P(H|p = 0.25 \cup p = 0.8)$. I don't see how this statement has an answer without placing a prior on $p$, or generally for any statement $P(A|B \cup C)$ except for the special case where $P(A|B) = P(A|C)$. My question is, are statements of the form $P(A|B \cup C)$ valid (outside of the Bayesian world)? Also, have Fine and Gray abused notation here? If so, is there a formal definition of the subdistribution hazard function?

Fine, J. P., & Gray, R. J. (1999). A Proportional Hazards Model for the Subdistribution of a Competing Risk. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 94(446), 496–509. https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.1999.10474144

Austin PC, Fine JP. Practical recommendations for reporting Fine-Gray model analyses for competing risk data. Statistics in Medicine. 2017; 36: 4391–4400. https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.7501 (Open access)



There seems to be a lot of overloading of meanings assigned to the variable $T$, in particular in $\bigcup [T \leq t \cap \varepsilon \neq 1]$ where each $T$ is different, each being the time of occurrence of the one of  previous causes of the failure-causing event.  Be that as it may, $P(A\mid B\cup C)$ is a perfectly legitimate conditional probability that has value $$P(A\mid B\cup C) = \dfrac{P(A\cap(B\cup C))}{P(B\cup C)} = \dfrac{P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C) - P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(B)+P(C)-P(B\cap C)}$$
